# how to add measures of the axis using parametric curves in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

Hi I wanna plot a curve in inkscape:
I need to add measures of the axis,
for x axis, [0, 0.5, 1]
for y axix, [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1]
But I didn' find any place to add them.
Anyone knows how to do that?

[image: parametric curves]

Comment: You should add them manually, or use the ruler Live Path Effect to add graduations. Remember, Inkscape is NOT a plotting software. Instead, you can for instance use Matplotlib to draw your figure, save it as SVG, then import it to Inkscape.

Answer (score 0):

Not actually an answer, only a supplement for an already given comment.

[image]

Extension Parametric curve gives to you only the coordinate axles and the curve. They are a combined path. You separate them by applying Path > Break apart. Then you can give to the curve a new stroke:

[image]

I guess you expect something like this (the coordinate axis measures and markers are only duplicated and rotated 90 degrees to make them fast):

[image]

It's an usual Inkscape drawing where the three paths from extension Parametric Curves were the starting point. What's added are simple Inkscape objects; texts and straight line segments.

There's no need to place every item separately, because Inkscape has good tools for duplicating, grouping, aligning and distributing objects.

But making this from scratch still took about 15 minutes, no matter I had a crystal clear idea and I have made graphs numerous times before this. Shortly: This is not productive when compared to actual math plotting programs. Making these in Inkscape can be recommended only if you need only a few of them or if you can use the same coordinate frame in several graphs as is or with only a few trivial edits. Or if you need some exercise to develop your skills with the basic tools.